# Is my solution for this probability question correct?

Tags: probability

Four fair dice are rolled. What is the probability of getting two different pairs?

So I used the multiplication rule here basically:

$$\frac{(6 \times 5 \times 1 \times 1) + (6 \times 1 \times 5 \times 1) + (6 \times 5 \times 1 \times 1)}{6^4} = .0694$$

Each number is the number of possible outcomes for each dice. The first dice always has 6 outcomes since it could be anything, the second one could be a different number or the same number as the first one. Lastly, the third one could be a number that matches the first dice or the second dice. Thus the following three are my possibilities: 6-5-1-1, 6-1-5-1, 6-5-1-1

Comment: This is hard to follow.  There are three ways to divide the four rolls into two groups of two (determined by the partner of the first roll, say).  There are $6$ possible values for the pair containing the first roll and $5$ possible values for the other pair.  Hence there are $3\times 6\times 5=90$ ways to throw two distinct pairs.  As there are $6^4$ ways to throw the dice without restrictions...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Another way to think of it is 6*1 for one pair and 5*1 for a distinct pair then multiply by 4 choose 2 to select which dice make one pair and divide by 2 because you don't care which pair you selected. Same number, though: 6*5*1*1*6/2